# Bad installation of 16.04 prevents backup of my old Ubuntu 14 partition

Tags: 16.04

I have been able with great difficulty to install a copy of Ubuntu 16.04 but for some reason it's running off the ISO CD and so very slow. Why it's there and not on the hard drive I don't know. I need to back up my old 14.04 partition on my network 2TB backup drive but Caja won't recognize it and also as  it doesn't "own" many of the files I want to back up. How can I load Caja or Nautilus as "user#1000"? I've tried gksudo caja and sudo -i and -s and -H, and it still doesn't have permission.

Comment: Did you take the disk out after installation?

Comment: It didn't ask me to and the computer kept accessing the CD for all application operations. When I shut it down, it asked me to remove the install media (which I did) and then it shut down. Now I can't get it to boot without the CD in place and it won't boot from any other boot source when I try using F2 to change the priority boot source. Sometimes it "boots" to a terminal with the (initramfs) heading which allows me to explore using the "ls" command. But since I have no idea what to do being a Linux/Ubuntu newbie, that doesn't help.

Comment: If there's nothing on the PC's connected drives that you wish to keep, and unless anyone has any better ideas here, I'd be tempted to reinstall again, ensuring that you ensure the installation wipes/uses all partitions (so disconnect anything you don't want wiped!)

Comment: How do I "disconnect" partition 5 which has all my Ubuntu 14 documents, email, downloads, etc.? I'd do that if I could only back up those files but I can't because Ubuntu says I don't have permission, i.e. I'm not the owner.

Comment: If you can successfully bootup on that device with the live cd you could consider using changing the owner of the files you want to copy with the  chown command. You'd need to sudo chown the files to be your user then it should be ok.  I'd like to think there's a way of doing this without chown though, as it's not ideal.

Comment: I'm working on my wife's computer. I just "reinstalled" 16.04 and then removed the install CD after it welcomed me. The desktop shows all the usual menus (applications, places, system, etc.) but it does nothing. When I put the CD back in, it works.

Comment: What's the command line I need to use for sudo chown?

Comment: click the ubuntu logo at the top right of the screen then type terminal in the text box.